# Jest throws error that is saved to a variable in some tests but not others

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am unit testing some methods on my TypeScript class using Jest. In an effort to use the DRY coding principle I assign an error to a variable and use it throughout the test. Sometimes, however, Jest is throwing the error like it's not being assigned.

Here's an example:

```
describe(`Jest Tests`, () => {
    let subscriptionId: string;
    let isActiveSubscription: boolean;

    beforeEach(() => {
      subscriptionId = 'ABCD1234';
      isActiveSubscription = false;

      mockSubscriptionModel = new SubscriptionModel(subscriptionId);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    test('This is a passing test', async (done) => {
      const connectionError = new Error('This is a DB connection error');

      DbClient.connect = jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(connectionError);

      try {
        const result = await SubscriptionModel.getActiveSubscriptions();
      } catch (err) {
        expect(DbClient.connect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(err).toEqual(connectionError);
        done();
      }
    });

    test(`This is a failing test`, async (done) => {
      const connectionError = new Error('This is a DB connection error');

      DbClient.connect = jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(connectionError);

      try {
        const result = await mockSubscriptionModel.addSubscription(
          subscriptionId,
          isActiveSubscription
        );
      } catch (err) {
        expect(DbClient.connect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        expect(err).toEqual(connectionError);
        done();
      }
    });
  });
```

Here is the error on the console:

```
 FAIL  test/models/Subscription.test.ts
  ● Subscription Model Tests › Jest Tests Tests › This is a failing test

    This is a DB connection error

      201 | 
      202 |     test(`Should fail if DB connection fails`, async (done) => {
    > 203 |       const connectionError = new Error('This is a DB connection error');
          |                               ^
      204 | 
      205 |       DbClient.connect = jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(connectionError);
      206 | 

      at test/models/Subscription.test.ts:203:31
      at test/models/Subscription.test.ts:8:71
      at __awaiter (test/models/Subscription.test.ts:4:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/models/Subscription.test.ts:202:63)
```

I am confused at why the first test would pass and the second would fail since they are practically the same code.

## Update 1

So with a little debugging, I have found that the line causing the error to be thrown is:

```
const result = await mockSubscriptionModel.addSubscription(
  subscriptionId,
  isActiveSubscription
);
```

So maybe it has something to do with declaring an instance the mock model? But I do have a similar test in another model which declares an instance of a class:

```
    test(`Should fail if bcrypt fails`, async (done) => {
      const bcryptError = new Error(`This is a bcrypt error.`);

      bcrypt.hash = jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(bcryptError);

      try {
        await mockUserModel.hashPassword();
      } catch (err) {
        expect(bcrypt.hash).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(bcrypt.hash).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockUser.password, 12);
        expect(err).toEqual(bcryptError);
        done();
      }
```

and that does not error either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here wasn't with the test at all. It was that the function never returned the error. I had to replace:

```
Promise.reject(err);
```

with

```
return Promise.reject(err);
```

to fix the issue.